# Gradle daemon not reused despite same java/gradle version

Tags: docker, gradle

I'm running gradle 5.6.2/Java 11 on a docker container as an unprivileged arbitrary user (no /etc/passwd entry) and building via `docker exec`. If I start the daemon via `gradle --foreground` and then run `gradle build`, the daemon is always deemed incompatible despite all environment variables and configuration being the same. Gradle lets me know `At least one daemon option is different` but fails to tell me what options are causing the issue or provide any useful context whatsoever. From the `--info` output, I cannot see any significant difference:

```
Found daemon DaemonInfo{pid=2349, address=[faff1188-7330-4666-8735-46fd97109411 port:33491, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1571244832816, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=ba368fe6-ab22-4d82-8780-a1b58dd80baf,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-
hotspot-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/var/gradle/daemon,pid=2349,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-Xms64m,-Xmx64m,-Dfile.encoding=US-ASCII,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} however its context does not match the desired criteria.
At least one daemon option is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/var/gradle/daemon,pid=2416,idleTimeout=null,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-U
NNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xms256m,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=US-ASCII,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant
]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=ba368fe6-ab22-4d82-8780-a1b58dd80baf,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/var/gradle/daemon,pid=2349,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-Xms64m,-Xmx64m,-Dfile.encoding=US-ASCII,-Dus
er.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]

  Looking for a different daemon...
```

How can I ensure my foreground daemon gets used -instead of having a new daemon start on each build and wasting excessive amounts of time?

Answer (score 0):

There are differences in both the additional `--add-opens` options and in the `xms`/`xmx` values. Look at the `daemonOpts` in the "Wanted" and "Actual" lines.

When you start a daemon with the `--foreground` option, it will not evaluate your project. So any options you have specified here (e.g. through `org.gradle.jvmargs`) will not be used.

However, you can set the same values used in your project in a `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable before starting the daemon. That should make it compatible. But why are you using that option in the first place?

Comment: I am using the --foreground option because I am doing my builds via `docker exec -u uid:gid -it <container_name> gradle build | awk ...` When that process has finished, the daemon is destroyed -so the only solution I have found is to explicitly run a gradle daemon. If there is another way to keep the build daemon alive, I am willing to try a different approach.