# Persisting gradle daemon after docker exec -it <container_name> gradle build

Tags: docker, gradle

I'm using `docker exec -it <container_name> gradle build` to run gradle (5.6.2/JDK 11) builds in a docker container. This approach works fine, but the daemon is destroyed after the command is completed. How can I keep the daemon running in the container after my build is complete?

I have tried `gradle --forground` but [have learned that this creates incompatible daemons and is an undesirable option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419074/gradle-daemon-not-reused-despite-same-java-gradle-version).

Answer (score 1):

This problem cannot be solved using Gradle. The daemons are lost because the Docker container stops. You should drop into an interactive shell instead:

```
docker run --rm -it gradle:5.6.2-jdk11 bash
```

Now run Gradle commands, and the daemon will be reused on subsequent commands:

```
root@014faa72d745:/home/gradle# gradle help
```

Once you're done, `exit` from the container:

```
root@014faa72d745:/home/gradle# exit
```

Note: You can use a bind mount to get your current working directory's files accessible in the container:

```
docker run --rm -it --mount type=bind,src=$PWD,dst=/app -w /app gradle:5.6.2-jdk11 bash
```

Comment: The container is still running. I run the build using docker exec. When the build is complete the daemon dies. If I run the build using docker exec nohup gradle build the daemon runs in the background. Ideally though, it should be able to persist without resorting to such measures.

Comment: Sorry then, I'm not sure how to fix it. I personally use the `--no-daemon` option for one-off Gradle tasks though (that is relatively faster, but still slow).